# creating a registration and login pages with localstorage

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a registration and a login page with javascript and localstorage and I am very confused with a few things.

Let's say all the info that needs to be saved is a string, and I want to have an array of these strings stored locally that can grow at any time and as long as it isn't cleared it keeps growing. I need to be able to parse through that array later and compare the strings with the string that will be inputted in the login page. How do I create an array of strings in local storage and access it? I tried the following: `localstorage.token = JSON.stringify(token);` but then every time there's a new token it re writes it. I read a few posts but I am still a bit confused.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show more code of yours? Yes, you can serialize your form and store this string in localstorage; you'll be able to fill all the fields from this cache by unserializing the form first. But I admit I'm a bit lost about why you're trying to serialize a _token_.

Comment: it's a little hard to show you my code, it's using a few non-generic frameworks. The basic problem I have is that I don't understand how the localstorage works. how to define a serialized localstorage to both add users at any time and be able to parse and look for the user. I am being lazy and connecting userNamePassword together as one string so that I don't have to worry avobut it too much. it's just basics.

Comment: Ok, check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pfgw/) (try to enter some data, then press Save, then enter some data again, then refresh the page). Is it that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Well, token is a string in your case, so if you stringify it, its value will change.

You don't need to, so just do :

```
localStorage.token = token;
```

You should use `JSON.stringify` only for object types:

```
var t = {a: 5, b: 'Tom'};

// set
localStorage.special = JSON.stringify(t);

// get
var u = JSON.parse(localStorage.special);
console.log(u.a); // 5
console.log(u.b); // 'Tom'
```

**EDIT:** About your registration/login process : http://jsfiddle.net/NAzZ5/

Comment: Erm... am I missing something obvious, or you indeed offer to store passwords in localStorage?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. what does localStorage.token do? apparently my localStorage.token is triggered to be true. What confuses me is how localStorage works, what does the .token, .sha1_pwd, etc. mean. are they arrays? how do I clear it and start from 0?

Comment: That was a bad idea :) Only store the token is better.

Comment: OK lets say I have all this crap saved on localStorage.token... how can I traverse through it in the login part?

Comment: So, register & connect functions are likely the same. createNewUser and connectUser functions will return the token, which will be necessary for future requests with the api. So, to determine if the local user is connected, depends on the existence of localStorage.token.

Comment: what really confuses me is the following... with an array, use a for loop or while loop, increment i and have [i] everywhere. how do I iterate through the values in localStorage.token?

Comment: well localStorage.token is a string, so if you want to compare with another string, you should use : `string_a.localeCompare(string_b)`

Comment: Hey thanks for your patience my friend! hopefully I'll get a grasp on this in a few! this framework is a nightmare but very interesting

Answer (score 1):

Ok, even though it's still rough at the edges, here's some [proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/3pfgw/):

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <input name='abc' value='' />
    <input name='def' value='' />
    <input name='ghi' value='' />
    <button type="button">Save</button>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    var $form = $('form'),
        $saveBtn = $('button'),
        myForm = {}, 
        myFormJsoned = localStorage.getItem('myform');

    if (myFormJsoned) {
        try {
            myForm = JSON.parse(myFormJsoned);
            $.each(myForm, function(i, obj) {
              $form[0][obj.name].value = obj.value;
            });
        }
        catch(e) {
            localStorage.removeItem('myform');
        }
    }
    $saveBtn.click(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('myform', 
            JSON.stringify($form.serializeArray()));
    });
});
```

The point is, when this button is clicked, the form is serialized into an array with that helping jQuery method (of course, using `serialize` would be even more simple - if `unserialize` were available). Then it's JSONed and stored into a single field of localStorage.

When you load the page, the process is reversed: JSON is parsed into Array of Objects (the result of jQuery.serializeArray), this AoO is inserted into a form back again (using convenience of `$.each`).

What's the concept, you may ask? My point is that it is certainly possible to work with localStorage as it were a single-string container - like cookie. But then again, I'd consider using separate container for each of the fields:

```
localStorage.setItem('myform_abc', $form[0].abc.value);
localStorage.setItem('myform_def', $form[0].def.value);
localStorage.setItem('myform_ghi', $form[0].ghi.value);
```

Comment: Ok now lets say you have only 1 input: `var token = String(Something)` n. This string will be stored locally easily like this `localStorage.token = token`. how do I iterate through all the values stored in `localStorage.token` so I can run a comparison? for the login part I mean.

Comment: Unserialize this token into `Array` (if you used `JSON.stringify` to tokenize it, `JSON.parse` to get it back), then iterate over this Array with `$.each` or just `for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++)` construct.

Comment: I think I get it, I'll keep ya posted. thank you for your patience, it's kinda hard to explain my situation without showing massive code.